# Configure Campaign with MoPub and AdMob

Tags: android, admob, mopub

We are migrating Android application from Google Ad's to MoPub. I have successfully integrated the android sdk and its loading fine.

On the MoPub login, I added AdMob in the network, and am trying to create a campaign to route all ad's from the network to the app. But when I Add New Campaign, I get 2 dropdown choices only Guranteed and Promotional. There should be a third "Network".

Am I missing a basic configuration step ?

Comment: Are you using AdMob's mediation framework or MoPub's mediation framework?

Comment: I hope to use MoPub so that I can use more than one network.

Comment: AdMob also has a mediation service so that you can use more than one network (see https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation).  MoPub is not directly supported yet, but you could use a custom event (https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/ads/mobile-ads-sdk/mediation/custom-events/) to implement MoPub through AdMob Mediation.  It's another route to consider.

Comment: Yes I realize that, but AdMob does not have iAds. I am hoping to tap that network.

Comment: Not on Android of course, but AdMob has direct support for IAd on iOS.  Check out the list of adaptes for networks directly integrated with AdMob.  (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/ad-network-mediation)

Comment: MoPub promises iAds on Android, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Interesting, I'm suprised iAd allows that.  Maybe they do server-side integration.  Even with AdMob Mediation custom events, I'm fairly certain you can't implement iAd on Android with client side code. So MoPub may be the right choice for you, if in fact they provide iAd on Android.

Comment: If and when I get it working, I'll post here. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't figured it out as yet, but the ad's started to work once I configured InMobi. Its possible that the network campaign runs by default and does not need a configuration specifically. I am yet to get confirmation for the same from the MoPub guys (report back later).

The other twist is that everytime you add a ad network to your list, you also need to include that library in your client (obviously). So I had to include GoogleAdMobAdsSdk.jar to my libs folder.

Keep in mind GoogleAdMobAdsSdk 6.0 version needs screenSize and smallestScreenSize in your configChanges for AdActivity in your manifest file. So if you want to support Android 2.3.3, you need to download GoogleAdMobAdsSdk version 4 from [here](http://search.4shared.com/postDownload/RpC3ihqM/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-411.html).

Comment: If you want to support lower versions of Android with the latest AdMob SDK, set your project.properties to android-13 or higher, and add to your manifest `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>` or whatever minimum version your app supports.

Comment: I'll try this and report back. Thanks.